# Magento 2 : Undefined variable: returnValue

Tags: magento2, sales-order, stripe

```
<?php

namespace StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Sales\Model\Service;

class OrderService
{
    public function __construct(
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Rollback $rollback,
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\GenericFactory $helperFactory
    ) {
        $this->rollback = $rollback;
        $this->helperFactory = $helperFactory;
    }

    public function aroundPlace($subject, \Closure $proceed, $order)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->rollback->reset();
            $returnValue = $proceed($order);
            $this->rollback->reset();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $helper = $this->helperFactory->create();
            \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Logger::log($e->getMessage());
            if ($order->getId())
            {
                // The order has already been saved, so we don't want to run the rollback. The exception likely occurred in an order_save_after observer.
                $this->rollback->reset();
                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                if (!$this->isAuthenticationRequiredMessage($msg))
                    $this->rollback->run($e);
                else
                    $this->rollback->reset(); // In case some customization is trying to place multiple split-orders

                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this how i can resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Add following code outside of try...catch block

```
$returnValue = null;
```

Your code looks like:

```
<?php

namespace StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Sales\Model\Service;

class OrderService
{
    public function __construct(
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Rollback $rollback,
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\GenericFactory $helperFactory
    ) {
        $this->rollback = $rollback;
        $this->helperFactory = $helperFactory;
    }

    public function aroundPlace($subject, \Closure $proceed, $order)
    {
        $returnValue = null;
        try {
            $this->rollback->reset();
            $returnValue = $proceed($order);
            $this->rollback->reset();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $helper = $this->helperFactory->create();
            \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Logger::log($e->getMessage());
            if ($order->getId()) {
                // The order has already been saved, so we don't want to run the rollback. The exception likely occurred in an order_save_after observer.
                $this->rollback->reset();
                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            } else {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                if (!$this->isAuthenticationRequiredMessage($msg))
                    $this->rollback->run($e);
                else
                    $this->rollback->reset(); // In case some customization is trying to place multiple split-orders

                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, i have tried that but it shows another error

Error: Call to a member function getAllItems() on null in
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Observer/SetHasDownloadableProductsObserver.php:36